# SendKeys bug prevents me from simulating keypress

Tags: c#, keypress, sendkeys

I have tried the following:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^q");
SendKeys.SendWait("^q");
SendKeys.SendWait("^(q)");
SendKeys.SendWait("^Q");
SendKeys.SendWait("^(Q)");
SendKeys.Send("^q");
SendKeys.Send("^(q)");
SendKeys.Send("^Q");
SendKeys.Send("^(Q)");
```

This is all while having focus on the program.

None of these work. They're suppose to simulate control (held down) + "q" according to [the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you read the question before you downvoted it? You do realize that you completely negated the purpose of the code when you put {^} right? It prints "^" I don't want it to print "^" I want it to use the functionality of a control + q.

    SendKeys.SendWait("{^}(q)");
    SendKeys.Send("{^}(q)");

These both print ^q. I want control + q simultaneously

Comment: Any chance you're doing this between two applications with different privilege levels?

Comment: No mate, I've used the "SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");" and it works.